# best command command to help add a line /etc/network/interfaces config file

Tags: command-line, nano

I am new to Ubuntu and I have been researching and doing practice but I couldn't figure out exactly the correct command to help me solve my problem. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out here. I want to know how I could use nano command to add the line "dns-servers" to the /etc/network/interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enter the command `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`.

The reason you have to prepend it with sudo is simply that the system configuration files is only writeable by root; not your everyday user.

When you've made the modifications you can exit `nano` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. You'll be prompted if you want to save your changes. Press <kbd>y</kbd> to select **Y**es. When prompted for filename, simply press enter to save to same filename as you opened.

Nano in addition shows a list of useful keys at the bottom. As per Unix convention ^ is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, so ^-C is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, whilst M is <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

`nano` is an text editor.

You can edit the file "*/etc/network/interfaces*"

with this command

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

If you are not logged in as root, you need to type 'sudo' before.

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

You can save with `CTRL+x` - `y` and `ENTER` to confirm